# can Elastic ignore case when using dynamic templates to index a geo_point?

Tags: elasticsearch, case-sensitive, geopoints

I'm running Elastic v7.4.2 and have a process that produces JSON records with uppercase keys:

```
{
  "TS": 1572559271.768669,
  ...
  "RESP_GEO": {
    "CITY": "Ashburn",
    "COUNTRY": "United States",
    "SUBDIVISION": "Virginia",
    "LOCATION": {
      "LON": -77.4728,
      "LAT": 39.0481
    }
  }
}
```

I created a dynamic template to automagically handle the timestamp and locations:

```
{
  "dynamic_templates": [
    {
      "dates": {
        "mapping": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "match": "TS"
      }
    },
    {
      "locations": {
        "mapping": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "match": "*LOCATION"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The ingest job throws an error:

```
field [RESP_GEO.LOCATION] of type [geo_point], caused_by "{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"field must be either [lat], [lon] ...
```

The `LAT` and `LON` attributes in the JSON are uppercase. Elastic wants them to be lowercase. Is there a way to force Elastic to ignore the case? Or convert all the keys into lowercase, inside Elastic, as a pre-indexing step?